# How to parse, actually get number from string in c#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to get only part with number. For example in input could be just number like 50, or string like: 50 and more. Also Number always will be on first place. And I want always to get only number from that. I tried like this, but this does not work:

```
double tendency;

var tendencyToString= Convert.ToString(tendency.ToString());
var tendencySplited = tendencyToString.Split(' ');
var tendencyNumber = tendencySplited[0];
```

Comment: "input could be just number like 50, or string like: 50 and more" in your sample `presureTendency` is a `double`. Please provide real code.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, right, but and point is that maybe my mistake is double, cause I make to this variable be double, to change to be string?

Comment: How can we know? Your input seems to be `string` and you want the user to enter a number. But it's absolutely unclear what you are struggling with. Provide sample input and what part you want to extract.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Input is as I wrote just number like 50, or entire string like 50 or more. I want to use only part with number in this case in both example number 50 I want to use.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the missing information and sample inputs with desired results. I could look in the crystal ball and understand that the user enters "abc50789foo123bah" and you want `50789`. But maybe that's wrong and you want `50789` and `123` or maybe that's invalid.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please then read my question. I clearly write that number is always on first place and also I write input could be JUST like I write 50 or (50 or more)

Comment: So if i enter "507.89foo123,456bah" you want only `507` or you want `507.89`?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Please read, I write 50, not 50 with coma or something decimal. I just want 507 in your example

Comment: How you know what the user will enter? You wrote the  input is a "string like: 50 and more", so starts with a number and the remaining part can be anything. But a number can contain decimal places, otherwise you have to say integer. My point is: we don't know your requirement and what provides the input and we don't know what result you expect. So its helpful to provide some examples and expected results.

Answer (score 2):

You can extract the number from the string using a regular expression.
See an example below. One thing to pay an attention to are your locale settings as they influence the format of the double.

```
string pattern = @"^\d+\.\d+";
string input = "50.1 , or more";
Match m = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
if (m.Success) {
    double nr = Double.Parse(m.Value);
    Console.WriteLine(nr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> So if i enter "507.89foo123,456bah" you want only 507 or you want
> 507.89? –

Please read, I write 50, not 50 with coma or something decimal. I just want 507 in your example

---

Well, then it's pretty easy:

```
string input = "50.1 , or more";
char[] digits = input.TakeWhile(Char.IsDigit).ToArray();
if(digits.Any())
{
    string result = new string(digits); // "50"
    // if you want an integer:
    int number = int.Parse(result); 
}
```